# does akka actor is sequence

Tags: akka, actor

I have a task that requires a thread pool, and each task needs to be executed in the same order as the call. So I used akka actor, but it not work as my expected， then I did a test.
Here is my code:

```
  @Test
  def actorTest1(): Unit = {
    for (i <- 1 to 300) {
      val actorRef: ActorRef = actorFactory.createActor("myActor")
      actorRef ! Tell(i)
    }
    Thread.sleep(6000000)
  }

  @Test
  def actorTest2(): Unit = {
    val actorRef: ActorRef = actorFactory.createActor("myActor")
    for (i <- 1 to 300) {
      actorRef ! Tell(i)
    }
    Thread.sleep(6000000)
  }

case tell: Tell => {
  Thread.Sleep(900)
  log.debug("tell: " + tell.i)
}
```

The log of test1, it's sequence is not as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5..., with different thread; case the test2's is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5..., but test2 always use the same thread. I want it work as the log is sequence with different thread, like:

```
2018-11-22 20:13:19.280 DEBUG 14176 --- [thread-1]       : tell: 70
2018-11-22 20:13:19.857 DEBUG 14176 --- [thread-2]       : tell: 71
2018-11-22 20:13:20.362 DEBUG 14176 --- [thread-3]       : tell: 72
2018-11-22 20:13:20.823 DEBUG 14176 --- [thread-4]       : tell: 73
```

Comment: why do you want it? In actorTest2, there is a single actor which works from time to time. There is no difference whether it works on the same thread or on different threads.

Comment: I edited my question, I mean, if it's on the same thread, there is no need to use threads(actor).

Comment: "I want it work as the log is sequence with different thread" - sorry, I do not understand what you want, because this is an incorrect sentence.

Comment: Just like executed as actor ! Tell(1), actor ! Tell(2), actor ! Tell(3), actor ! Tell(4)...
and in the controller, the log is 
thread-1: tell: 1, thread-2: tell: 2, thread-3: tell: 3, thread-4: tell: 4...
the thread is different(thread-1,2,3,4...), and param received is tell :1,2,3,4...

Comment: executor chooses first available thread. All threads are equal. You should not bother which thread runs this or that actor. You cannot control this because it has no sense.